Issue with the Comments column with the Append to changes in existing text
Here are examples of what is going on  regarding our comments in the SharePoint.
This is what happened to our comments when someone in IT processed a ticket and did not test the request in a dummy production. Our comments need to get reverted back to its original format .
This is still wrong and needs to get back to its original format . Refer to yellow.
This is still wrong and needs to get back to its original format . Refer to yellow.
Here are examples of what is going on  regarding our comments in the SharePoint.
This is what happened to our comments when someone in IT processed a ticket and did not test the request in a dummy production. Our comments need to get reverted back to its original format .
Hoffmeister, LG (Lisa) (12/20/2023 5:47 AM):
<div>Rec&#39;d from customer with cc to Nate Strang at Vermeer WI: Lisa, We
<br>purchased the drill and trailer from Vermeer but have not yet received the
<br>title to be able to register it.  Nate
<br>have you been able to find the title for us yet?  Melanie I emailed Ben to see where and when it was sent and let Melanie know I would respond shortly.</div>
Hoffmeister, LG (Lisa) (12/18/2023 3:05 PM):
<div>Emailed both email all lien info.</div>
Hoffmeister, LG (Lisa) (10/17/2023 6:43 AM):
<div>2023 Behnke trailer vin 4L5SC2927PF066336 msoasset $26,375.00state WIDLLFS liencustomer doing Timothy Thielbar 608-628-0553melanie.tekcomm@yahoo.com; timschevys@yahoo.com
<br>Dealer Ben Brouws</div>**


Here is a correct version on how our comments should reflect in Sharpoint..Original format …Compare to what is in yellow above .. See the difference

Brancato, C (Christine) (3/27/2024 4:32 PM):

2024 Utility Trailer vin    1UYVS2533R6066312      mso 
state will be IL
dllfs will be lien
dealer is karen kwak

